# How to keep leading zeros in a column when reading CSV with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, types

I am importing study data into a Pandas data frame using `read_csv`.

My subject codes are 6 numbers coding, among others, the day of birth. For some of my subjects this results in a code with a leading zero (e.g. "010816").

When I import into Pandas, the leading zero is stripped of and the column is formatted as `int64`.

Is there a way to import this column unchanged maybe as a string?

I tried using a custom converter for the column, but it does not work - it seems as if the custom conversion takes place before Pandas converts to int.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas read\_csv dtype leading zeros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16929056/pandas-read-csv-dtype-leading-zeros)

Comment: @firelynx That question was asked a year after this one.

Answer (score 92):

As indicated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17903594/4518341) by [Lev Landau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2626623/lev-landau), there could be a simple solution to use `converters` option for a certain column in [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) function.

```
converters={'column_name': str}
```

Let's say I have csv file `projects.csv` like below:

```
project_name,project_id
Some Project,000245
Another Project,000478
```

As for example below code is trimming leading zeros:

```
from pandas import read_csv

dataframe = read_csv('projects.csv')
print dataframe
```

Result:

```
      project_name  project_id
0     Some Project         245
1  Another Project         478
```

Solution code example:

```
from pandas import read_csv

dataframe = read_csv('projects.csv', converters={'project_id': str})
print dataframe
```

Required result:

```
      project_name project_id
0     Some Project     000245
1  Another Project     000478
```

---

To have **all columns** as str:

```
pd.read_csv('sample.csv', dtype=str)
```

To have **certain columns** as str:

```
# column names which need to be string
lst_str_cols = ['prefix', 'serial']
dict_dtypes = {x: 'str' for x in lst_str_cols}
pd.read_csv('sample.csv', dtype=dict_dtypes)
```

Comment: str as class in `dict_dtypes = {x : str  for x in lst_str_cols}` but I think `'str'` still works

Answer (score 35):

here is a shorter, robust and fully working solution:

simply define a mapping (dictionary) between variable names and desired data type:

```
dtype_dic= {'subject_id': str, 
            'subject_number' : 'float'}
```

use that mapping with `pd.read_csv()`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(yourdata, dtype = dtype_dic)
```

et voila!

Comment: you can also include many other datatypes, `float` and others. I believe this is the most pandasque solution

Comment: query: in dtype_dic json, why is str without quotes but float in quotes?

Comment: I had to loop through different CSVs with different columns. This function took all the column mappings and didn't error out when a column wasn't there in the table. So I was able to define all the columns (to be read as string) in all the different tables in just one `dtype_dic` and use it for all the csv's. Thanks!

Comment: I believe this is the best solution as well :)

Comment: This did not work for me (python3.6, pandas 0.22.0); I still lost my leading zeros.

Comment: @SummerEla what is the `dtype` of your column? are you using `read_csv` as indicated?

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ I tried casting both datatypes to strings and objects. I thought this would be simple, but it's just not working.

Comment: what do you mean object? you should either use str or numeric

Comment: Yep, I was in pandas, not pure python.. hence object instead of string.

Answer (score 16):

If you have a lot of columns and you don't know which ones contain leading zeros that might be missed, or you might just need to automate your code. You can do the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv("your_file.csv", nrows=1) # Just take the first row to extract the columns' names
col_str_dic = {column:str for column in list(df)}
df = pd.read_csv("your_file.csv", dtype=col_str_dic) # Now you can read the compete file
```

You could also do:

```
df = pd.read_csv("your_file.csv", dtype=str)
```

By doing this you will have all your columns as strings and you won't lose any leading zeros.

Answer (score 6):

You Can do This , Works On all Versions of Pandas

```
pd.read_csv('filename.csv', dtype={'zero_column_name': object})
```

Comment: Also, If you need to do this for all columns you can do `pd.read_csv('filename.csv', dtype=object)` so you won't have to account for every column

Answer (score 2):

You can use `converters` to convert number to fixed width if you know the width.

For example, if the width is 5, then

```
data = pd.read_csv('text.csv', converters={'column1': lambda x: f"{x:05}"})
```

This will do the trick. It works for pandas==0.23.0 and also `read_excel`.

Python3.6 or higher required.

Answer (score 1):

As an example, consider the following my_data.txt file:

```
id,A
03,5
04,6
```

To preserve the leading zeros for the id column:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("my_data.txt", dtype={"id":"string"})
df
```

```
   id  A
0  03  5
1  04  6
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can specify a column type the way you want (if there haven't been changes reciently and if the 6 digit number is not a date that you can convert to datetime). You could try using `np.genfromtxt()` and create the `DataFrame` from there.

EDIT: Take a look at  Wes Mckinney's [blog](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/?p=543), there might be something for you. It seems to be that there is a new parser from `pandas 0.10` coming in November.

Comment: the features in that issue are done on the c-parser branch now and should be coming in 0.10. I just made a quick for issue #2184 and will be included in 0.9.1 coming up real soon. But yes, using dtypes should be the preferred behavior here so just keep a lookout for 0.10 in like a month or so.

Comment: you should be able to make it work now if you upgrade to the latest on github master (i.e., using a converter)

Comment: @ChangShe thanks, with the latest github version my converter work indeed! Looking forward to 0.10 for a cleaner solution though...

Comment: Wes Mckinney's blog page is 404.