# Pandas while importing ignores 0 from the values if it starts with 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I've used pandas to import a csv file as below:

```
import pandas as pd
csv_input = pd.read_csv('Accounts_Input.csv')
```

but after importing, while checking the values it seems that it ignored the 0 from the values if it start with a 0 as below:

```
input_file  after_import
0897456129  897456129
8601009624  8601009624
```

Can u guys suggest any way to avoid this?

Comment: There are multiple answers on this, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250046/pandas-csv-import-keep-leading-zeros-in-a-column

Comment: @Vaishali Thanks! That answered my question!