# How to I export data with leading zeros from Pandas to CSV preserving the leading zeros in csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a pandas data frame in which one column contains data with leading zeros.I want to export the data frame in CSV by preserving leading zeros. So I tried following code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
os.chdir(path)
x=np.array(['0134','0567','0012','0009'])

df=pd.DataFrame(x,columns=['Test'])
df.dtypes
df.Test=df.Test.astype("str")
df.to_csv("leadingZero.csv")
```

But in leadingZero.csv I'm finding 0's in one column & number discarded zeros in another column

Can you guide me how do I preserve leading zeros in CSV?

Comment: Should work as expected... are you opening `leadingZero.csv` in a text editor? Or are you perhaps opening the file in Excel..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas csv-import: Keep leading zeros in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250046/pandas-csv-import-keep-leading-zeros-in-a-column)

Comment: "are you opening leadingZero.csv in a text editor" seriously? why do you even ask such a question. Do you think senior management of a corporation would open that file with a text editor? ...

Answer (score 2):

- To keep the leading zeros use `df.Test.astype("str")`.
- To remove index column use: `index=False` in `to_csv` method.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = np.array(['0134','0567','0012','0009'])

df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['Test'])
df.Test = df.Test.astype("str")
df.to_csv("leadingZero.csv", index=False)
```

Output (`leadingZero.csv`):

```
Test
0134
0567
0012
0009
```

#### View the CSV in Office application with leading Zeros

If you use Office application to open the CSV select the column as Text. I am using `Libre Office Calc` in an Ubuntu machine.

- While opening the CSV file, select the column as `Text` field.

[image: Select column as text field]

- The sheet will have leading zeros:

[image: CSV file with leading zeros in Libre Office]

If you are using Microsoft Excel, follow [Microsoft's documentation on Format numbers as text](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/format-numbers-as-text-583160db-936b-4e52-bdff-6f1863518ba4).

Comment: I recommend using this solution, since it is using the internal vectorized functions, while Prateek Mishra's answer uses lambda (not recommended) in a element-wise fashion (also not recommended).

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is with csv file. If you open csv file using different formats like wordpad, notepad, etc., leading zeros will appear

Use `apply('="{}".format)` on the column where you want to preserve the leading zeros

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Test': ['0134','0567','0012','0009']})
df['Test'] = df['Test'].apply('="{}"'.format)
df.to_csv('withLeadingZeros'+'.csv', index = False)
```

output from `withLeadingZeros.csv`

[image]

Comment: This is the BEST solution across tons of totally useless answers where people suggest to use astype and so on. Thank you so much