# Convert to_datetime when days don't contain leading zero

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, strftime

I'm trying to get the index of my dataFrame to be of type datetime. My CSV file contains seperate columns of Dates and Times which i combine upon importing:

```
df = pd.read_csv("example.csv", sep=";", decimal=",", parse_dates=[["Date", "Time"]])
```

It will look like this after the import:

|  | Date_Time |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1012020 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 1012020 00:15:00 |

The problem is the missing leading zero on the first 9 days of each month. Pandas `to_datetime()` needs a leading zero for the `%d` format option to work. When i use `format="%d%m%Y%H:%M:%S"` python says "invalid syntax"

How can I convert this column to datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.zfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html) (as suggested by @FObersteiner in the comments) and apply [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) afterwards:

```
import pandas as pd

# changing 2nd val to `'12012020 00:15:00'` to show that 
# only the 1st val is affected
data = {'Date_Time': {0: '1012020 00:00:00', 1: '12012020 00:15:00'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Date_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date_Time"].str.zfill(17), 
                                 format="%d%m%Y %H:%M:%S")

print(df)

            Date_Time
0 2020-01-01 00:00:00
1 2020-01-12 00:15:00

print(df['Date_Time'].dtype)
datetime64[ns]
```

Another (admittedly, unnecessarily complicated) way to go, would be to use a regex pattern to replace all "dates" with 7 digits by their 8-digit equivalent:

```
df['Date_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(
    df['Date_Time'].replace(r'^(\d{7}\s)',r'0\1', regex=True),
    format="%d%m%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Explanation `r'^(\d{7}\s)'`:

- `^` assert position at start of the string
- `\d{7}\s` matches 7 digits followed by a whitespace
- The encapsulating brackets turn this into a `Capturing Group`

Explanation `r'0\1'`:

- `\1` refers back to the `Capturing Group` (1st of 1 group(s)), to which we prepend `0`

Comment: Reads like you could achieve the same with str.zfill(8), no? But what if `1012020` means 10th of January?

Comment: @FObersteiner: yes, hadn't thought of that. `df['Date_Time'].str.zfill(17)` should work (17 for the whole string). `1012020` will not mean 10th of January. As specified by the OP: only the day is missing the leading zero. So, 10th of January would be `10012020`.

Comment: I tried both but pandas seems to be the problem here. @ouroboros1 Trick worked but pandas removes the leading 0 again. The column is of type pandas.core.series.Series. I tried the solutions from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250046/how-to-keep-leading-zeros-in-a-column-when-reading-csv-with-pandas but it had no effect...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Trick worked but pandas removes the leading 0 again"? At what point is the "trick" working/at what stage does pandas seem to remove the 0 again? If you simply do `print(df['Date_Time'].str.zfill(17))`, does it show the strings as `01012020 00:00:00`, `01012020 00:15:00`, etc. with a leading 0, when required? And are you getting an actual error, or is the result just not what you expected. If the former, please share the error; if the latter, what exactly is the result?

Comment: @ouroboros1 Okay so i do `df["Date_Time"].str.zfill(17)` which will print out `0        01012020 00:00:00`. However if I do `df["Date_Time"]` in the next cell the output will be `0        1012020 00:00:00` again, without the leading zero. So it doesn't seem to get overwritten?

Comment: It's not an `inplace` operation. You need to overwrite the value of `df["Date_Time"]` for pandas to keep the change. So, use: `df["Date_Time"] = df["Date_Time"].str.zfill(17)`. But the full line would simply be: `df['Date_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date_Time"].str.zfill(17), format="%d%m%Y %H:%M:%S")`